# Regex dentro do SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

Como recuperar campos com o seguinte padrão?

`a111/1111` ou `a111_1111` ou `a111-1111` ou `a111+1111`

onde:

a = alguma letra do alfabeto;

1 = qualquer digito de 1-9;

Eu montei um `Regex` que está funcionando perfeitamente: `(^[a-z]{1})([0-9]{3})(\W)([0-9]{4})` porém não consigo aplicar no SQL Server, tentei utilizando o [LIKE como nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255396/sql-like-to-regex) exemplo:

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Campo like '%(^[a-z]{1})([0-9]{3})(\W)([0-9]{4})%'`

ou

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Campo like '%[(^[a-z]{1})([0-9]{3})(\W)([0-9]{4})]%'`

mas não funciona, existe um modo de fazer uma consulta usando um Regex?

Segue uma imagem do Regex dando match:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O separador é somente um dos caracteres */* *_* *-* e *+*? Você utilizou \W na expressão.

Comment: É que /W acabou servindo, pois se fosse um outro número no local do caractere especial o ([0-9]{3}) não daria match pois ele pede só 3 e não 4

Comment: Então o quinto caractere é qualquer um, desde que não seja algarismo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avalie a seguinte solução:

```
-- código #1 v2
SELECT colunas
  from tabela
  where coluna like '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][/_+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

Se o padrão procurado pode estar em qualquer posição da coluna, eis uma variante do código acima:

```
-- código #2 v2
SELECT colunas
  from tabela
  where coluna like '%[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][/_+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][-9]%';
```

Embora nativamente o T-SQL não ofereça expressões regulares, é possível implementar através de rotinas CLR. Eis artigo que disponibiliza uma opção: [CLR Assembly RegEx Functions for SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

Documentação:

- [[ ] (Wildcard - Character(s) to Match)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql)
- [[^] (Wildcard - Character(s) Not to Match)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-not-to-match-transact-sql)

Comment: Então eu não posso utilizar aquele recurso do regex de contador ?

Comment: Exemplo quero 8 digitos ai eu uso [0-9]{8} ao invés de [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Que eu tenha conhecimento, em T-SQL não é possível o uso de {} para indicar o número de ocorrências.

Comment: Vou marcar como correta, a unica coisa que ficou incorreta é [/_+-] pois aqui se aplicaria num codigo a111/_+-1111, o correto é utilizar um OR, mas sua resposta ajudou 100%

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Quanto ao quinto caractere, utilizei [/_+-] porque são os caracteres que constam no exemplo. Caso possa ser qualquer caractere, exceto algarismo, experimente substituir [/_+-] por [^0-9]

Comment: Teria alguma forma de pegar, por exemplo, registros que tenha só ponto ou só vírgula?
Vamos supor que eu queira retornar tudo dentro de uma coluna do tipo varchar que tenha só virgulas ou só pontos, sem nenhuma letra.